# Object as session value in Django

Tags: python, django, session, object, mechanize

I want to use an instance of mechanize as a session variable in django because it has cookies. (Building some web app that parses data of a website with login)

```
        browser = mechanize.Browser()

        browser.open('https://www.somewebsite.html')
        browser.select_form(nr=0)
        browser.form['j_username'] = 'test'
        browser.form['j_password'] = 'test'

        browser.submit() #now browser has cookies in this instance

        request.session['browser'] = browser   #this doesn't work
```

So that didn't work, so I tried using a cookiejar so that I could put that as session variable but I guess it leads to the same problem that I am trying to put an object as session variable...

```
        cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
        browser.set_cookiejar(cj)
        #some code here

        request.session['cj'] = cj #doesn't work again
```

What would be a way to do this? I'm bit clueless :/

Comment: use middle ware to store ur session values

Comment: request.session['username'] = 'hello' like that I have sessions working. Just not possible to pass an object like in my post?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/ have u seen this Doc, if not will be useful:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django uses [Pickling](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html) to serialize objects into session values. My guess is that the mechanize `Browser` object has not implemented the Pickle serialization protocol, and thus cannot be converted into a valid string that can be loaded back into a Python object.

I think your best bet is probably to extract the cookies from the `Browser` session and convert them into a string, save them to your user's session, and re-instantiate a `Browser` object with those saved cookie values (if mechanize allows that). Good luck!

Comment: Mmmm yes that would be a way hopefully :D I go try it. Thanks